# Migrating Vite Project form Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vuejs3, vite

I have Vue project with vite .this project was created in windows but when I move my project to ubuntu it does not work. when i run the project using

```
npm run dev
```

the result is vite did not found
what could be the problem and could not figure out in google

what I tried, when the project could not be run I remove the node module and reinstall it in ubuntu. but this does not help

Comment: Did you install the dependencies? npm i

Comment: yes I installed all the dependencies

Comment: Can you please clarify "does not work" and "does not help", thanks

Comment: i mean my project still does not work